# Double binary relationship with weak entity vs ternary relationship

Tags: database-design, uml, relationship, class-diagram

I have a problem that states that a group of servers send daily data through a group of data lines. Each server has an id and each data line has an id. I've come up with a couple of ideas but I'm not sure which is better. From what I've read it's always preferable to avoid ternary relationships when something can be done in terms of binary relationships. But in my case I came up with the following binary relationship

`(Server)[serverId]--1--------1..* --(DailyData)[date]--1..*----------1--(DataLine)[dataLineId]`

where DailyData is weak towards Server, as many servers will have reports on the same date. In the end, I would get a Server table with `(serverId)` as PK, a DailyData table `(serverId, date)` with a combination of both as PK, and a DataLine table `(serverId, date, dataLineId)` with a combination of the three as PK. This (if I did it correctly) seems to work.

My other idea is to use a ternary relationship between Server, Date and DataLine, which seems more elegant and has no weak entities. The relationship table would just be `(serverId, dataLineId, date)` with the three of them serving as PK, which kind of arrives at the same conclusion as my other solution, but in a more elegant and straightforward way.

Which would be a preferable solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind of relationship that you describe would in UML be be an [association class](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/associationclass.html):  `DailyData` makes no sense without a `Server` and a `Dataline`:

[image]

An association class is at the same time a binary association and a class. An instance thereof cannot exist without a linked server and a linked data line, and this is exactly what you try to model.

The `{id}` in UML indicates that an attribute is part of the identifier of the class.  It's close to the concept of primary key, although UML defines no further its semantics.  The `Date` would be part of the identifier of `DailyData` as it would allow to distinguish between several dates for the same server and data line.

To implement an association-class in a database, you would typically use an [association table](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/associationTableMapping.html), also known as join-table.  Since you speak of  "weak" and other concepts that are not UML,  I'd add that in an ERD, the closest to an association class is an "[associative  entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)".

There is by the way no such thing as a weak entity in UML.  The closest is a composite aggregation (black diamond), as the life cycle of the weak entity depends on the life cycle of its owner.  It is however not allowed in UML to have the same instance being component of two  different composite aggregations. So in UML, the association class would be the best option for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The course I'm doing kind of mixes ERD concepts into UML diagrams and we are asked to add primary keys, weak entities, etc. to the UML diagram. I'll check with the teacher if we can use the attribute of the associative class as a PK together with the server and dataline

Comment: I didn't know that in UML, it is not allowed "to have the same class being component of two different composite aggregations". Do you have a reference to the UML specs where this is specified? I had expected that it would be allowed e.g. to have class Wheel, aggregated in both Car and Motorcycle, even though, of course, an instance of Wheel cannot be part of a Car and a Motorcycle at the same time.

Comment: @daniel indeed. For weak entites,  the full pk is usually composite and is made of an attribute (weak identifier) of the weak entity combined with the pk of the owner. For the implementation of the association class this is a valid technique. However,    it does not exclude the use of  a surrogate key instead: a unique key that is generated for each new instance of the association class. The two non null foreign keys would be sufficient for giving an equivalent implementation. UML is totally agnostic in this regard.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl let me correct, it's not the class that cannot be component, it's the instance.  See p112 (section 9.5.3, just under the table of aggregation forms):  "Composite aggregation is a strong form of aggregation that requires a part object be included in at most one composite object at a time." I suppose the reason is that if an instance could be part of two composites,  there would be an ambiguity as to which one is responsible for its lifecycle.

Comment: Yes, thank you for changing your answer.